# onLongPressGesture frame in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to replicate a long press button effect like the Apple default one, but with a custom style.

I have a custom view where I call `onLongPressGesture`. The issue is that the `pressing` variable is getting set to false even though my finger is still pressing.

I just move my finger outside the the views onLongPressGesture frame.

I want the `pressing` variable to not get set to false when I move my finger outside the frame area.

How can i achieve that?

Here's my code:

---

```swift
.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1000000000, maximumDistance: 100, pressing: {
    pressing in
    if !pressing {
        self.action?()
        self.showNextScreen = true
    } else {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            self.showGrayBackgound = true
        }
    }
}) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `maximumDistance` parameter to set how far outside the view the gesture applies:

```swift
struct LongPressView: View {
    @State var isPressing = false
    let action: ()->()

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(isPressing ? Color.orange : .gray)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1000000, maximumDistance: 1000, pressing: { pressing in
                self.isPressing = pressing
                if !pressing { self.action() }
            }, perform: {})
    }
}
```

A sufficiently large `maximumDistance` will be outside the boundary of the screen and the long press will remain active until it's released. However, the macOS behavior where you click and hold while dragging outside the frame and back so that the button's state is turned off and back on isn't possible with a `LongPressGesture`. Once outside the `maximumDistance`, the gesture is complete.